# How to display a grid-list of registered users under specific role with custom user meta data in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I am trying to display a grid list of registered users under specific roles such as subscriber, editor, etc with custom metadata. I've started with this below code but it only displays the avatar and the name when need to display some more data of each user such as website link, description, email.

Here is the code snippet I am using-

```
function wpb_recently_registered_users() {

    global $wpdb;


    $recentusers = '<ul class="recently-user">';

    $usernames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename, user_url, user_email FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5");

    foreach ($usernames as $username) {

        if (!$username->user_url) :
            $recentusers .= '<li>' . get_avatar($username->user_email, 45) . '<a href="' . $username->user_url . '">' . $username->user_nicename . "</a></li>";
        else :
            $recentusers .= '<li>' . get_avatar($username->user_email, 45) . '<a href="' . $username->user_url . '">' . $username->user_nicename . "</a></li>";
        endif;
    }

    $recentusers .= '</ul>';


    return $recentusers;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_newusers', 'wpb_recently_registered_users');
```

I need to get these user meta key data also -

```
mepr_email, mepr_your_bio, mepr_youtube_channel
```

but not sure how to integrate with the above code snippets. Can anyone help me find a better solution, please?

Comment: to read meta value just use `$username->mepr_email`

Comment: I tried this $username->mepr_email  but it shows nothing.

Comment: oh yes, you have to search users with the function [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to use `$username->mepr_email`

Comment: Hi Kaperto, 

If you don't mind, could you give me an example actually I am not very used to with php query?

Answer (score 0):

So I am using this code snippet and getting all the required data but I am not sure how to run this as a loop so as soon as a new user register it will get the data like posts query? Sorry I have limited knowledge in this.

```
'function user_data_code(){ 
 $blogusers = get_users( array( 'search' => 'admin' ) );
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
echo '<span>' . get_avatar($user->user_email, 45) . '</span> <br>';
echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . '</span> <br>';
echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</span> <br>';
echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->first_name ) . '</span> <br>';
echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->mepr_bio ) . '</span> <br>';
echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->mepr_website_link) . '</span>';
}

}
add_shortcode('wpb_newusers', 'user_data_code');'
```